# 3D animation software for anatomy

Tags: 3d, animation, modeling

I am looking for a 3D animation software to create an animation of the anatomy of the neck while swallowing, but i have no experience at all with any 3D animation software. Also, it would be best if the software comes with some models to work on. I have heard of blender, but I guess that there is a huge ramp up to get good results and I don't know if it provides basis models.

I think of doing something like:
A person is seen from the outside, then it zooms in to see the anatomy of the neck, then the person starts to swallow and the swallowing mechanism is shown. From that, I could add the feature I want. There is many video that does that, so I guess this is possible to avoid to create it from scratch.

So, do you have any software to recommend so that i do not spend time uselessly? would you still recommend Blender?

Comment: Although this is not what you are seeking, you may find it very helpful: https://www.zygotebody.com

Comment: This is great, if i could adapt something like this and add animations, it would be close from what i need.